# Integer solution for $n_1 k_1 + n_2 k_2 + n_3 k_3 = 1$

Tags: diophantine-equations

For  given integers $k_1,k_2,k_3$ is there an integer solution for the following equation: $$n_1 k_1 + n_2 k_2 + n_3 k_3 = 1$$

Comment: Have you heard of Bezout's Lemma?

Comment: No I have not. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

[Bezout's Identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) says that for any given integers $n_1$ and $n_2$ there are integers $k_1$ and $k_2$ so that
$$
k_1n_1+k_2n_2=\gcd(n_1,n_2)
$$
Simply extending this, we get that for any given integers $n_1$, $n_2$, and $n_3$ there are integers $k_1$, $k_2$, and $k_3$ so that
$$
k_1n_1+k_2n_2+k_3n_3=\gcd(n_1,n_2,n_3)
$$
Thus, there is an integer solution for
$$
k_1n_1+k_2n_2+k_3n_3=1
$$
if and only if
$$
\gcd(n_1,n_2,n_3)=1
$$